# can't understand systemc '<<' operation

Tags: operator-keyword, systemc

im looking 'risc-cpu' code which is in systemc library(specifically 'example' folder) but i can't understand what << operation in main.cpp is.
   in main.cpp they instantiate each module and do << operation with many sc_signal variable.
i think it's something like binding operation but i want to know exactly.

below is some code from main.cpp

```
fetch   IFU("FETCH_BLOCK");      //instiate module fetch
    IFU.init_param(delay_cycles);  //module fetch delay for delay_cycles
    IFU << ram_dataout << branch_target_address << next_pc << branch_valid
        << stall_fetch << intreq << vectno << bios_valid << icache_valid
        << pred_fetch << pred_branch_address << pred_branch_valid << ram_cs << ram_we
        << addr << ram_datain << instruction << instruction_valid << program_counter
        << intack_cpu << branch_clear << pred_fetch_valid << reset << clk;

decode  IDU("DECODE_BLOCK");   //instanciate module decode as IDU
    IDU << reset << instruction << pred_instruction << instruction_valid
        << pred_inst_valid << out_valid << destout << dout << dram_dataout
        << dram_rd_valid << destout << fdout << fout_valid << fdestout
        << branch_clear << dsp_data_valid << program_counter << pred_on
        << branch_instruction_address << next_pc << branch_valid
        << branch_target_address << mem_access << mem_address << alu_op
        << mem_write << alu_src << reg_write << src_A << src_B << forward_A
        << forward_B << stall_fetch << decode_valid << float_valid << mmx_valid
        << pid_valid << pid_data << clk;
```

Comment: You need to find the header defining IFU and IDU and start looking for where the << operator overload is defined.  I don't think this is standard systemc syntax.

Comment: it's going to be something sensitivity related.

Comment: thanks. as you said << operator was overloaded and it said it is used as positional binding. i still don't understand what positional binding is but thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

`<<` is the standard left shift operator which in C++ is overloaded to also function as a put-to-stream. It appears to me they're simply writing a lot of values to `IFU` and `IDU`.